# change numbers into stars?

Tags: javascript

I have this code witch works fine to change the number one into a star, but if I want several numbers like 1-5 to change into the same amount of stars(*) as the number is could I do this within the same loop or do I need to create 5 diferent loops, one for each number?

```
function changeNumber()
{
    var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("grade");
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var text = element.innerHTML; 
        var x = text.replace('1','*');
        element.innerHTML=x;
    }

}
```

this code gets the values the user typed in and places it in a array...

```
var button = $('#add');
    button.click(function() 
    {
        //funktion för vad som ska hända när man klickar på knappen
        var filmnamn = $('#name');
        var filmnamnet = filmnamn.val();
        var betyg = $('#star');
        var betyget = betyg.val();
        betyget = Number(betyget);

        if(filmnamnet == 0)
        {
            $('#name').css('background-color', 'red');

        }
        if(betyget == 0)
        {
            $('#star').css('background-color', 'red');

        }
        if(betyget == 0 || filmnamnet == 0)
        {
            alert("Vänligen fyll i fälten korrekt");

        }
        else
        {
            var array = new Array();
            array.unshift(betyget);
            array.unshift(filmnamnet);
            film_array.unshift(array);
            betyg_array.unshift(array);
            updateFilmList();

        }

    });
```

Then the function updateFilmlist looks like this...

```
    var film_list = $("#filmlista");
    var film_array = new Array();        

function updateFilmList()
    {
            document.getElementById("name").value = '';
            document.getElementById("star").value = 0;
            var filmen = film_array[0][0];
            var grade = film_array[0][1];
            var element = '<li class="lista">' + filmen + '<span class="betyg">'+ grade +'</span></li>';
            film_list.append(element);
            changeNumber();

    }
```

And when I added the code you showed me in the changeNumber function the only number thats get changed into a star is the first list element in the dynamically created list... then the rest just shows up as numbers, why is that? btw you can ignore betyg_array since its for another function and has nothing to do with the problem...

Comment: so you mean if text is 2 replace with ** and 3 replace with *** etc?

Comment: yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 4):

A oneliner for you:

```
var str = '8 rabbits, that\'s 16 rabbit ears';
str = str.replace(/(\d+)/g,function(a){return Array(+a+1).join('*')});
//=> ******** rabbits, that's **************** rabbit ears
```

[**explanation**]

`/(\d+)/g` extracts sets of consecutive digits (`\d`) from the string (e.g. '1', '15').

The callback function returns a joined array with n elements = the found set of digits                                 converted to Number (`+-operator`, here `+a`) `+a+1+1` (add 1) because join of an Array with n empty elements 'string'  returns a string with length n-1.

[**bonus**] You could extend `String` like this

```
String.prototype.replaceNumbersWithStr = function(str){
   str = str || '*'; // default to '*';
   return this.replace(/(\d+)/g,function(a){return Array(+a+1).join(str)});
}
// usage examples
'8 rabbits, that\'s 16 rabbit ears'.replaceNumbersWithStr();
 //=> ******** rabbits, that's **************** rabbit ears

'8 rabbits, that\'s 16 rabbit ears'
   .replaceNumbersWithStr('<span class="star"></span>');
 //=> <span class="star"></span><span class="star"> ...
```

And a bit more sophisticated:

```
String.prototype.Num2Str = function(str){
   str = str || '*'; // default to '*';
   return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g,function(a,b){return Array(+b+1).join(str)});
}
// usage example
'{2} rabbits, that\'s 4 rabbit ears'.Num2Str();
 //=> ** rabbits, that's 4 rabbit ears

'Stars: {2}'.Num2Str('<span class="star"></span>');
 //=> Stars: <span class="star"></span><span class="star">
```

Comment: Awesome - +1 for Being able to go beyond 9!  Can you explain the syntax that extracts the numerical value of the digits you matched?

Comment: If I could +1 it again, I would!

Answer (score 3):

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NqCNf/2/)**

You don't need a condition for each or a loop.

```
function changeNumber(){
    var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("grade");
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var length = parseInt(element.innerHTML);
        var x=Array(length+1).join("*");
        element.innerHTML=x;
    }
}
```

Comment: this only seems to work for the first span element, then the others just shows up as numbers... the script i made works as when i push a button a list element with a span element is created then another function is suppose to change the number to x amount of stars...

Answer (score 2):

`Array(5).join("*")` will give you a string of 4 stars. I'm sure you can figure it out from there.